# Find where Regex.Match failed

Tags: c#, regex

I want to know which Regex Groupcollection failed to match.

e.g.:

My pattern detects `VIEW start page` or `VIEW end` via:

```
match = Regex.Match(string, @"(^VIEW)\s*((?(1)(?:(start)\s*((?(1)page$))|(end$))))");
```

I want to know if I give the input string as "VIEW go" how to find that the second group failed.

Comment: Can you show us sample input and expected output? I don't think you can find out about a particular failed group, and if you can - it won't be readable or simple. You could instead chain several regex expressions, starting with broad, such as `^VIEW\s*.*$` , then going through something like `^VIEW\s*(page|end)$` and make a decision tree out of such expressions to determine what's missing

Comment: Make the 2nd group optional by using ? which indicates zero or 1 time match.

Comment: My program should only accept the string "VIEW start page" and "VIEW end". If we give an input as "VIEW go" i need to give an error message as "Expected start page or end after VIEW".How to do this using Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to check the latter group to verify if your regex matches something or not.

The **Match** Object returned by the method allow you to check this using:

```
if ( match.Success )
    Console.Write("Success!");
else
    Console.Write("Expected start page or end after VIEW");
```

For you purpose you can also simplify your regex as this:

```
match = Regex.Match(string, @"^VIEW\s+(?:start\s+page|end)$");
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB4nD4/1).

**UPDATE**

If you want to refine the error message you can try something like this:

```
match = Regex.Match(string, @"^VIEW\s+(?:(start\s+page|end)|(.*))$");

if (match.Success) {
    if ( match.Groups[1].Success)
        Console.Write("Success!");    
    if ( match.Groups[2].Success)
        Console.Write("Expected start page or end after VIEW");
} else {
    Console.Write("usage: VIEW [start page|end]");
}
```

A running code demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/XMlm9G)

Comment: Thanks, But if VIEW is not there i need to print another error message.Is it possible?

Comment: @Akash: i've updated the answer to fulfill your request

Comment: Thank you for the help. Also if i enter "VIEW start" i need to display "Expected page after VIEW start".Is it possible?

Comment: @Akash: it's possible grouping ``start`` and ``page`` separately but if you need to proceed this way it's better to split the string by ``\s+`` and implement a little state machine that process a token after another.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help, appreciate it